# How navigate from loginscreen after clicking on logout button in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, logout, stack-navigator

i'm trying to implement a logout functionality in react native.The users will land to `homescreen` after logged in , which contains a side bar . Logout button is within the side bar.I'm using  stack navigator from react-navigation for navigating from one screen to another.I've tried like the below ,but there is a mistake it will direct to a blank screen when clicked on logout button.

```
onPressLogout(){
     AsyncStorage.removeItem('userdetail');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
    alert('You have been logged out.');
}
```

Currently i'm writing this code within `homescreen`. Where do i write the code for logout ?Does it be within `Sidebar`?Also how to navigate Please help.

**Updated**

```
  const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
         login: {screen: LoginScreen},
         register: { screen : RegisterForm },
  },

     {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: true,
  color:"#aa4a00",
  tabBarOptions: {
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 15,
      fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeueBd',
      color: '#4B4C4B',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    indicatorStyle : {
      backgroundColor: '#aa4a00'
    },
    style : {
      borderBottomColor: '#ebcccc',
     // borderBottomWidth: 10,
    },
    tabStyle: {
    activeBackgroundColor : "#aa4a00",
    inactiveBackgroundColor: '#dddddd',
    upperCaseLabel: false
  }
  }
     });
const StackScreens = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: MainNavigator,
    },
    CourseListing:{screen: CourseListing},
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    EconomicNews: {screen: EconomicNews},
    EconomicDetails: {screen: EconomicDetails},
    CategoryDetail: {screen: CategoryDetail},
    DetailedView: {screen: DetailedView},
    IndividualSection: {screen: IndividualSection},
    Mcq:{screen: Mcq},
    QASection: {screen: QASection}
})

export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
   Home: {
     screen: StackScreens,
  },
  Profile: {
      screen: Profile
  },
  FAQ: {
      screen: Faq
  },
  LogOut: {
      screen: LogOut
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please post your StackNavigator-Code or even more related code concerning this issue.

Comment: i've updated my qs please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');` should change to `this.props.navigation.navigate('MainNavigator');` or `this.props.navigation.navigate('login');`

Because you call your `LoginScreen` `login`

Comment: Yeah working thank you..but i tried this by adding button in `homescreen` other than `sidebar`. I want the logout button within `sidebar` so where do i write the code for `onPressLogout`?Do i need to create a page for that?

Comment: where is your sidebar? `mydrawer`, `stackscreen`

Comment: You could put it where ever you want. If you put it on `sidebar` and the `sidebar` is not in the `navigation` then you have to send `this.props.navigation.navigate` over. Otherwise if you use it on those screens above. Then just put the code in.